# Custom lookup_field with django rest framework, Cannot resolve detail

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The error I am getting is

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /usercombo/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "usercombo-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

In my view.py

```
class UserComboViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows UserCombo to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = UserCombo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserComboSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,EmailConfirmationPermission) 
    lookup_field='customURL'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return  UserCombo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

In my serializer.py:

```
class UserCombo(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    customURL = serializers.CharField(
       required=False,)

    data = JSONSerializerField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserCombo
        unique_together = (("product", "user"),)
        fields = ('url', 'user', 'product', 'data', 'customURL', 'is_active')
        lookup_field ='customURL'
```

If I remove the two lookup_field lines everything works fine, but the lookup_field for the usercombo object is the pk.

Comment: Make sure `customURL` is part of the `UserCombo` model. Definition  `lookup_field` - The *model* field that should be used to for performing object lookup of individual model instances.

Comment: It is a char field in the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like using lookup_field was removed as an option for ModelSerializer.Meta in django-rest-framework version 3.2.  This error is because of this removal. It should still be possible to use lookup_field with extra_kwargs.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.2-announcement/